# How can i properly encode names of foreign languages into the name of .txt file in php

Tags: php, encoding

I want to encode names of people into the name of a `.txt` file

Now i am using code below to make the names lowercase, strip out spaces and without accented chars:

```
$raw_authorname = 'Charlène Rodriës';

$stripped_authorname = preg_replace("/[^a-z.]+/i", "", $raw_authorname); // strip accented chars out authorname
$stripped_authorname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $stripped_authorname); // strip out spaces
$stripped_authorname = strtolower($stripped_authorname); // make lowercase

echo $stripped_authorname; // output: charlnerodris
//And the txt file will be: charlnerodris.txt
```

This works all fine with latin letters.
The problem appears when the name is per example a russian name: `Юлия Преснякова`

I cannot create a `.txt` file with this name: `Юлия Преснякова.txt`
Same problem with arabic names.
So i thought; maybe it is best to encode the name and create a `.txt` file with the encoded name.
What is the most appropriate method to encode these names?
Or is there a better way to change the names accordingly, that i can create always a name for the txt file?

Comment: Maybe the error is later in your code, where you create the file. And usually "strip accent" means removing the accent but keeping the letter. [check the infinite libraries to "slug"ify names

Comment: Maybe [Transliterate a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php)?

Comment: Transliterate is a good option! Thnx for the advice